# Mongodb limit fields to return in hierarchical document

Tags: mongodb

I've went through mongodb document:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/
on how to limit return data.
I have a following structure:

```
{
  "2015": {
    "m1": "0",
    "01": {
      "m1": "0",
      "01": {
        "m1": "0"
      },
      "02": {
        "m1": "0"
      }
    },
    "02": {
      "m1": "0",
      "01": {
        "m1": "0"
      },
      "02": {
        "m1": "0"
      }
    }
  },
  "_id": "1234"
}
```

This is a time  hierarchy that aggregates m0 value for days, months and year. I will have more metrics than m0 on each level, this is a simplification.
The document will be relatively big and I usually need only values for specific day/month/year: 2015.m0, 2015.01.m0, 2015.01.01.m0 and I was hoping that I could query only those specified fields, so I tried something like:

```
find({_id: "1234"}, {"2015": 1,"2015.01": 1,"2015.01.01": 1})
```

But it only takes the last one into consideration and returns 2015.01.01.m0 value.
Does it mean that if I would like to use this feature I would have to rather specify all fields that I don't won't with 0?

UPDATE:
I would expect something like:

```
{
  "2015": {
    "m1": "0",
    "01": {
      "m1": "0",
      "01": {
        "m1": "0"
      }
    }
  },
  "_id": "1234"
}
```

So only values on a specified level of a hierarchy.

Comment: Could you show us a result document of what you expect? That would be easier to understand.

Comment: Your last projection "2015.01.01" is a subset of field 2015 and 2015.01 thus it only returns fields under "2015.01.01". This is an expected and understandable behavior.

Comment: I added expected result in an update.